# Why do I get a requirements error when trying to install Ruby with RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I would like to install Ruby 2.0 with RVM on my Ubuntu system and get an error message:

```
rvm 1.23.5 (master)
ubuntu 12.04 (LTS)

**---- Error message: -------**
rvm install 2.0.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system.....................................................................................................................................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.0.0-p247',
please read /home/emzett/.rvm/log/1381812161_ruby-2.0.0-p247/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Answer (score 6):

Update the system using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Try:

```
rvm remove 2.0.0 # uninstall rvm
rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
rvm requirements # check if there are any dependencies that need to be installed.
rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

Comment: deleted comment and will add answer

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by editing

```
etc/apt/source.list.d/medibuntu.list
```

I just commented the line referring to medibuntu out.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/pcjpcj2/5443017

I recommend this gist.

if you need Ruby on Rails 4.0 ~ , best answer is here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ran the following command to fix it:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Then I remembered that I failed installing a package earlier that day. What this command did was resolve the dependencies on that package and allowed RVM to do its thing.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when there are broken sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d or /etc/apt/sources.list.d

You can run Ubuntu Software update to see if there are any any failures due to broken sources, if so, follow the below steps

- fix them or comment and execute the following steps
- rvm requirements -- this will install all of
  the required software modules
- rvm list -- provides you the available versions of ruby
- rvm install ruby-x.x.x  -- This will install x.x.x version of ruby, please change the ruby-x.x.x with the version you are interested in ex (ruby-2.1.0 for 2.1.0 version of ruby)