# rvm requirements error on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I got Ubuntu Saucy Salamander(13.10) as OS and trying to do

```
rvm requirements
```

But allways got an error on "Updating system" stage. Here is my log:

```
rvm requirements
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system...............
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ',
showing last 15 lines of /home/uhtshka/.rvm/log/1388083633/update_system.log
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/conky/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/conky/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Already tried solitions represented here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947072/error-while-installing-ruby-using-rvm
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373560/why-do-i-get-a-requirements-error-when-trying-to-install-ruby-with-rvm
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373560/why-do-i-get-a-requirements-error-when-trying-to-install-ruby-with-rvm/19375476#19375476
https://gist.github.com/pcjpcj2/5443017
```

But all this was useful for me. Can somebody help me with that?

**UPDATE 1:**

also tried get heads:

```
rvm get head --autolibs=3
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /home/uhtshka/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /home/uhtshka/.profile /home/uhtshka/.bashrc /home/uhtshka/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /home/uhtshka/.bash_profile /home/uhtshka/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /home/uhtshka/.rvm/ is complete.

# uhtshka,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.
```

and this solution:
    https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83885/ruby-2-0-0-install-via-rvm-errors-surrounding-openssl?newreg=96e7044a2e0b4126986b10ab8dc28cf3

same problem on requirements stage

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade at first? `rvm get head`

Comment: Follow this - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83885/ruby-2-0-0-install-via-rvm-errors-surrounding-openssl?newreg=96e7044a2e0b4126986b10ab8dc28cf3

Comment: Yes. Just tried and than try again `rvm requirements`

Nothing changed

Comment: already try to reinstall. Same problem with `rvm requirements`

Comment: @ArupRakshit, its not related to rvm in OSX. You wont be prompted for the saucy/main i386 packages in OSX...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by following this advice:

```
$ rvm autolibs read-fail
$ rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/13.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p484.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Missing required packages: gawk libgdbm-dev libffi-dev
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

After that I just installed missed requirements packages and the result for rvm requirements was:

```
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
```

Thanks everyone for attention!

Comment: did it work without any problems like in the output from `rvm requirements`?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by doing  -

```
$ rvm autolibs disable

$ rvm install 1.8.7
```

(Grab and install manually the packaged which are missing, In my case following packages were missing)

```
$ sudo apt get install gawk libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev \
  libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev \
  libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev

$ rvm requirements

$ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Hope you will get success with above mentioned steps.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is to solve the rvm requirment error returns 100

If any deb command is commented in /etc/apt/sources.list than try to uncomment that command from /etc/apt/sources.list

Command is:

$sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list

If problem is not solved than replace sources.list file with other Ubuntu's sources.list

Command is:

$mv  /etc/apt/sources.list

Please make a backup before doing that

Command is:

$cp /etc/apt/sources.list sources_backup.list

Problem should solve by this time, if not than reinstall the Ubuntu.

Note: If sources.list file is corrupted than it will gives problem to install other packages.

Answer (score -1):

I have done this by:

```
$ rvm autolibs disable

$ rvm install 1.9.3
```